# Lwuit VideoComponent goes to the background of the form when played on Samsung TouchScreen Mobiles

Tags: android, java-me, lwuit

I am using Lwuit videocomponent to play some media as 3gp, mp4 etc.
The problem occurs when the component is started, it plays but immediately goes to the background. This happens only on Samsung TouchScreen devices Such as Corby, GT S5620, Duos.

the code i am using is as follows:

```
                    videoComponent = VideoComponent.createVideoPeer(filePath);
                          player = (Player) videoComponent.getNativePeer();
                          player.prefetch();
                          player.realize();
                          player.start();
                          videoComponent.setVisible(true);
                          f.addComponent(videoComponent);
```

The media is played for just a sec and immediately goes to background.

Thanks!

Comment: But here I am using Lwuit 1.5 how should I integrate lcdui with lwuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video component in LWUIT had many issues most of which we fixed in [Codename One](http://www.codenameone.com/).

Comment: Thanks! Since, I have built the code using Lwuit 1.5. How should I  migrate to the Higher version? The whole project were required several months to complete.

Comment: Its not a higher version its an entirely new project with quite a different approach. You need to create a new project in Codename One and migrate the import packages, remove the MIDlet related code etc.